# compiling with local copy of gcc, incompatible libstdc++

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I have a very similar issue to the one presented in [how to dynamically link to local copy of libc.so.6, libstdc++.so.6 on system with old version of gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056646/how-to-dynamically-link-to-local-copy-of-libc-so-6-libstdc-so-6-on-system-wit) and I followed the answer provided there. To summarize, the issue is that I have code written using C++11 and the cluster sysadmin won't upgrade the gcc compiler to a version which supports C++11. I did a manual install of gcc4.9 in my home directory (using --prefix=$HOME). I compile my code with the following flags:

```
-I/home/stroberg/include -L/home/stroberg/lib -lc -lstdc++ -llapack -lblas -O3 -std=C++11
```

I also set

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/stroberg/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

The compilation goes fine until it gets to the linking stage, where I get the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/stroberg/lib/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/stroberg/lib/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/stroberg/lib/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/stroberg/lib/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/stroberg/lib/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/stroberg/lib/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
```

Any ideas what could be causing the problem? I'm also using the armadillo package (also a local version) is that makes any difference.

Thanks.

Comment: In my experience you shouldn't need to use any special flags to compile or link programs using your local version, it should find all those things on its own.

Comment: I can confirm that eliminating the `-lc` and `-lstdc++` flags doesn't change anything. However, the problem remains.

Comment: Also before running any programs built with the local compiler I think you'll need to add the installed lib folder to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. You can put it in a script to launch your program or set it in `$HOME/.bashrc` `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib` or `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib64`

Comment: If you set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `$HOME/.bashrc` then you will need to open a new terminal to run programs in it or else log out and log back in for it to affect the whole session.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that I also set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: I can't think of anything else. I installed it myself a few weeks ago. As long as you didn't move it from where you configured it to be installed it should just find its own libraries from the `--prefix` you gave it. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should only be needed for running the programs. All I can suggest is that you try again following the instructions on the GNU site: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/build.html Don't follow those instructions that you linked:

Comment: From the error messages, it seems to be finding the libraries ok. The problem appears to be that they're incompatible.

Comment: Are you sure you're launching the correct GCC executable? `$HOME/bin/g++`? (taking into consideration any configured pre/postfix). And put your local `$HOME/bin` on the `PATH` (in front of the previous `$PATH`)?

Comment: To avoid any confusion, I put a simlink in my `$HOME/bin` so that `$HOME/bin/g++49` points to `$HOME/bin/g++`. I then use `g++49` in my Makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, so I figured I should post what I did. Compiling with

```
-I$(HOME)/include -L$(HOME)/lib -lblas -llapack -lgsl -lglsblas -O3 -std=c++11
```

seemed to do the trick. Wish I knew exactly what fixed the problem, but I hope this helps.